# Cant login to Developer Apple account - connection not secure

Tags: mac, certificate, anti-virus, https, safari

When I want to login to `developer.apple.com` on Safari I have error that Safari can't establish secure connection to https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login?appIdKey.....

I could do that before update to 10.13.4. I use Avast security, I have read that it causes problems but I did not have any before update. Should I add idmsa.apple.com to whitelist?

Any other website that has valid certificate is working perfectly, like stack overflow.

Comment: Avast typically has a module that scans encrypted HTTP traffic, by doing this, it basically breaks all HTTPS traffic due to the fake certificate it must use to do this.  Do you have that feature enabled?  I suggest you uninstall Avast to determine if that is the case.

Comment: @Ramhound if i add domain to whitelist it works and Apple login site shows with Apple certificate authority.

Comment: You added the domain to which whitelist?  I assume to a whitelist within Avast?  If you did add the domain the whitelist, and doing so solve the problem, what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Ramhound my concern is that on previous macos, before last update I was able to login without this problem, like five days ago.

Comment: Avast continuously updates their list of insecure domains.  It could be as simple as a false positive on their part.  You didn't answer my question about the whitelist though.